# Is there an alternative to the kill system call?

Tags: linux, signals

Is there an alternative to the kill system call? An alternative, yet similar system call that can simply send a signal to a process?

Comment: *An alternative, yet similar system call that can simply send a signal to a process?* as opposed to what `kill` does? simply sends a signal to a process? from the man page of kill(2) - **kill - send signal to a process**

Comment: [`pidfd_send_signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_send_signal.2.html)?

Comment: Even `kill pid` does not send a KILL signal. The default is SIGTERM, which can be caught or ignored by the target if it chooses. SIGKILL is a last resort, and used to be documented as "Terminate with extreme prejudice", a CIA term for "assassination".

Answer (score 2):

`kill()` **does** send a signal to a process.  From its manpage:

```
The kill() system call can be used to send any signal to any
process group or process.
```

The same is true for the `kill` command. So for instance to send a SIGHUP to process 1138 (this is usually done to tell the process to reload its configuration) you would use

```
kill -1 1138
```

Your confusion stems probably from the fact that the most common use of the `kill` command is to kill a process (by sending the SIGKILL signal).

Comment: not sure what the most common use is, esp. nowadays when people seem to suggest `kill -9` rather freely, but of course the _default_ is SIGTERM, and not SIGKILL.